# Why is node.js "filehandle.readLines()" giving me "TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function"?

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

I'm trying to learn about how Node works with files, and going through the filesystem docs.

Currently I'm trying to use the `filehandle.readLines()` method but am hitting a brick wall and it's driving me mad!

The problem is that, any time I try to `console.log` within the function that calls `readLines()` I get the following error:

TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function

I started with my own code, but have now reached the point of copying the code in the Node docs, but the error persists. Here is the current iteration:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { open } = require ("node:fs/promises");


async () => {
    const file = await open("/Users/max/Documents/node-fs-fun/input.txt");

    for await (const line of file.readLines()) {
      console.log(line);
    }
  })();
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried putting the console.log elsewhere within the function and I get the same result.

I am expecting each line of the target file to be logged to the console, but instead I'm just getting the same error over and over again: `TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function`

Comment: did you modify the console object?

Comment: Nope! That's the complete code. Console log works fine outside the anonymous function.

Comment: That can't be the whole code, there are syntax errors.

Comment: Really? I can't see any - and like I said ultimately this is copied from the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadlinesoptions